# Check if current request url is controller index

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does somebody know a way of checking if the current request its URL is targeted to a controller its index page?

In my application I have about 30 controllers with each an index page. I have an ActionFilter which sets a cookie on each request in its OnActionExecuting event. However I want it to be set only when the user visits an index page. I'm aware that all of the following URL's will return the index;

- http://xxxx/controllerName/index
- http://xxxx/controllerName/
- http://xxxx/controllerName

Anyone know the best way of checking this?

Before anyone asks, the ActionFilter I'm using is the following:

```
public class RefreshDetectFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshFilter"];

        filterContext.RouteData.Values["IsRefreshed"] = cookie != null && cookie.Value == filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("RefreshFilter", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Kind regards and thanks in advance,
Yannick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current Action like this, regardless of the URL containing the action name or not:

```
filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems that all 3 url requests I listed up return "Index" as action. Thanks!